# T-SQL: How to have an Auto-Increment variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml

I am writing a set of complex XML queries. A lot of them are hierarchical queries like `Select x , (select y from tbl2 for xml) from table1 for xml` etc. I wish I could get a way to add an auto increment variable to add here like this:

```
Select 
    @incr as [@ID], x as [@Title], 
    (select @incr as [@ID], y as [@Title] 
     from tbl2 
     for xml path('node')) 
from 
    table1 
for xml path('node')
```

I wish the variable @incr to return an integer that increments every time I use it.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear to me what you want your query to do.

Comment: Have you try to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) as [@ID]`? ;).